# paperclip not uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip

I have followed the steps given [here](http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/gem-paperclip-uploading-files-and-pictures-into-your-rails-application/) but the images are not getting uploaded.

The following is the log for server :-

```
Started GET "/pics/thumb/missing.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-14 16:53:22 +0530
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pics/thumb/missing.png"):
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/stark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/stark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/stark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Also note that the guide is for Rails 3 and you seem to use Rails 4.1, so there may be inconsistencies.

Comment: This code is just here because the image is not uploaded, and the default path when image is blank is `/pics/thumb/missing.png`. The problem is above.